# Element contained within a predicate?? Tattoo error...

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Hey so my friend got a tattoo of logical symbols to translate some quotation, and this friend ended up having a statement of this form contained in the proposition:
$\forall y[P(y) \rightarrow (y \notin Q(x))]$
I saw this as problematic, as P an Q being unary predicates, they are a relation operation and not a set of elements, so $y\notin Q(x)$ makes no sense.  Let me know if this is valid or not, it's no my tattoo but my friend would very much like to know. Thanks

Comment: I admire your friend.

Comment: I have moments every now and then where I have to scramble to the nearest category theory textbook and check my tattoo for the $n$-th time. Good luck to your friend, the paranoia can be terrible :p

Answer (score 1):

Here, I believe that what is meant is for $$Q(x) = \{x\in \text{domain}\mid Q(x) \,\text{is true} \}$$

So I suspect that the intent in declaring any element $y$ to not to be an element of $Q(x)$ was to mean, in effect, $\lnot Q(y)$.

So taking $y$ to be in the relevant domain, I suspect what was meant was

$$\forall y(P(y) \rightarrow \lnot Q(y))$$

But as noted in Andreas' comment below, there is a problem with this interpretation, in that we really do not have any bound on $x$ in its appearance in the tattoo, and its appearance on the left of the above attempt to make sense of what is meant by the "set" $Q(x)$.

Comment: The equation attempting to define $Q(x)$ suffers from the problem that $x$ is free on the left side and bound on the right.

Comment: I do see the problem, @Andreas. I'm simply trying to make sense of the intent of the OP's friend's tattoo, not condoning it! I just edited to make this more explicit.

Comment: Thanks, I saw multiple issues in it but it's too late now, not sure I should even mention it now lol.  Just wanted to know exactly why this is problematic.

Comment: I'd try to let your friend "off the hook." I certainly wouldn't bend over backwards to assure him it is "spot on", but I wouldn't tear it apart either, given the permanence of the tattoo. (It's not like he can ask for a "do-over"!)

Comment: Yea I noticed this mistake and was wondering if there was a simple fix, like maybe covering something up or adding a small negation somewhere but it seems the issue is much more deeply rooted than that.  Oh well

Answer (score 0):

Since $x$ is not bound, this expression is a function of $x$.  It makes sense, but it is not a statement.  A statement would be $\forall x$ (this expression), or $\exists x$ (this expression), or $\forall x\forall z,~ (z\to x)\to$ (this expression).

Answer (score 0):

In order for "$y\in Q(x)$" to make sense, $Q(x)$ will have to be a set, and therefore $Q$ will have to be a set-valued function, not a predicate.  Interpreting $Q$ this way (and interpreting $P$ as a unary predicate), the formula is OK; its truth value will depend not only on these interpretations of $P$ and $Q$ but also on the value of the free variable $x$.  Whether it corresponds to the quotation your friend had in mind is another question (which I fear is likely to have a negative answer).

Comment: Unfortunately for my friend, the Q was meant to be a predicate and would not make sense as a set valued function.  Oh well, that's why I would always consult Stack Exchange before permanently inking a delicate formula onto my body!